# How to enable asp compatiblity mode on Razor page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, vb.net-2010

I'm trying to get credit card processing for a friends website. The processing will be through authorize.net.  The sample code is written in classic asp.  I've been trying to run it, but the following piece is giving me an error:

```
objRequest = Server.CreateObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP")
```

I'm getting the following error:

> {"The component 'Microsoft.XMLHTTP' cannot be created.  Apartment threaded components can only be created on pages with an <%@ Page aspcompat=true %> page directive."}

How do I enable asp compatibility mode with the Razor engine? The page directive is not the same as aspx.  I tried creating an aspx view for just that page, but of course it won't use the master page and it threw a few other errors.  I'd really like to get this working with Razor.  Any thoughts?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to look at either the C# sample code or the VB.NET sample code (Depending on your language of choice).

They are written in ASP.NET format.

http://developer.authorize.net/downloads/samplecode

Comment: Great!  I didn't even think to check there!  I had a friend setup the CC processing and he only gave me the classic asp samples.  While the site doesn't provide MCV, I think the VB.NET code for posting the request should work.  Thanks!

Comment: Also, please upvote and mark this post as "Answered" if this solved your issue! :)

Comment: I tried to upvote, but I need 15 reputation.  Only have 1 right now since I'm new.

Comment: Marked answered. Better late than never!